# Setting listener on button used in expandable list view

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

i m trying to use expandable list.the design part is working fine but when i m setting a listener on the button the application crashes with a message:"unfortunately your application has stopped working".following is the application details for reference,please if someone knows how to set a listener on the button in the parent node of an expandable list please let me know.Thanks a lot in advance:

the application manifest file:

> 

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.expandablelist.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

main activity xml layout file:

```
  <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <ExpandableListView 
  android:id="@+id/expandable_list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
  android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
  android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent">
 </ExpandableListView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

xml layout file for parent node:

```
  <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
  <TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/list_item_text_view"
   android:textSize="20sp"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:background="#ff000000"
   android:textColor="#ffffffff"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_marginLeft="35dp" />
  <Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="button"
   android:focusable="false"
   android:layout_gravity="right"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
   android:id="@+id/button"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

xml layout file for child node:

```
  <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/list_item_text_child"
   android:textSize="20sp"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:background="#ff000000"
   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Mainactivity named as Myactivity code:

```
package com.example.expandablelist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private ExpandableListView mExpandableList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
mExpandableList = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);
ArrayList<Parent> arrayParents = new ArrayList<Parent>();
ArrayList<String> arrayChildren = new ArrayList<String>();
//here we set the parents and the children
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
//for each "i" create a new Parent object to set the title and the children
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.setTitle("Parent " + i);
arrayChildren = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
arrayChildren.add("Child " + j);
}
parent.setArrayChildren(arrayChildren);
//in this array we add the Parent object. We will use the arrayParents at the       setAdapter
arrayParents.add(parent);
}

//sets the adapter that provides data to the list.
 mExpandableList.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(MyActivity.this,arrayParents));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_my, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

code for parent class:

```
package com.example.expandablelist;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Parent {
// private String mTitle;
private String mTitle;
    private ArrayList<String> mArrayChildren;
    public String getTitle() {
  //return mTitle;
return mTitle;
}
 public void setTitle(String mTitle) {
   //this.mTitle = mTitle;
this.mTitle=mTitle;
  }

 public ArrayList<String> getArrayChildren() {
 //return mArrayChildren;
return mArrayChildren;
  }
  public void setArrayChildren(ArrayList<String> mArrayChildren) {
//this.mArrayChildren = mArrayChildren;
this.mArrayChildren=mArrayChildren;
  }

  }
```

code for mycustomadapter class:

```
  package com.example.expandablelist;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.database.DataSetObserver;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
  private LayoutInflater inflater;
  private ArrayList<Parent> mParent;

  public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Parent> parent){
  mParent = parent;
  //inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }


   @Override
   // //counts the number of group/parent items so the list knows how many times calls       getGroupView() method
  public int getGroupCount() {
  return mParent.size();
  }

  @Override
  //counts the number of children items so the list knows how many times calls    getChildView() method
 public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
 return mParent.get(i).getArrayChildren().size();
 }
 @Override
 //gets the title of each parent/group
 public Object getGroup(int i) {
 return mParent.get(i).getTitle();
 }

 @Override
 //gets the name of each item
  public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
  return mParent.get(i).getArrayChildren().get(i1);
  }
  @Override
  public long getGroupId(int i) {
  return i;
  }

  @Override
  public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
  return i1;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean hasStableIds() {
  return true;
  }

  @Override
  //in this method you must set the text to see the parent/group on the list
  public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

  if (view == null) {
  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_parent, viewGroup,false);
  }
  TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);
  //"i" is the position of the parent/group in the list
  textView.setText(getGroup(i).toString());
  //return the entire view
  return view;
  }

 @Override
 //in this method you must set the text to see the children on the list
 public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
 if (view == null) {
 view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_child, viewGroup,false);
 }
 TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_child);
  //"i" is the position of the parent/group in the list and 
 //"i1" is the position of the child
 textView.setText(mParent.get(i).getArrayChildren().get(i1));
 //return the entire view
 return view;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
return true;
 }
 @Override
 public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
 /* used to make the notifyDataSetChanged() method work */
 super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
 }
}
```

Comment: Please add the logcat output of when the application crashes

Comment: Error log will help in finding the cause of crash. Using a clickListener in the adapter class will be a good way. You can do it in getGroupView if you want listener on group parent node.

Comment: i m writing the code for the listener in the getgroupview() method which is meant to return only the view.so i know that i m placing the code at a wrong place.so can someone tell me by taking reference from the above code about where i should place the code for the listener on the button

Comment: Do you still need help? I just saw that, but It have been a month since last comment. Is It solved? I can help you